# rich:fileUpload stackoverflow error at AjaxOutputTracker.getAjaxOutputs

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, stack-overflow

I am currently migrating to richfaces 4.5, JSF2.2 and also add primefaces-6.0 (for other feature that is not supported by richfaces)
I am using Tomcat 8 for the server.

At the xhtml file, I just put simple code below just to test this :

```
<rich:fileUpload id="upload"
     fileUploadListener="#{cc.attrs.beanPage.uploadListener}"
     maxFilesQuantity="1"
     acceptedTypes=".ppt, .pptx, .doc, .docx, .txt, .xls, .xlsx, .zip, .pdf"  />
```

and at the uploadListener I only put some thing just to debug

```
 public void uploadListener(FileUploadEvent event) {
    this.item = event.getUploadedFile();
    String projectFileName = this.item.getName();
 }
```

When I debug I see it reach the listener and end without error. But I am getting this error below after the listener finished:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:679)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:643)
    at org.richfaces.context.AjaxOutputTracker.getAjaxOutputs(AjaxOutputTracker.java:86)
    at org.richfaces.context.AjaxOutputTracker.getAjaxOutputs(AjaxOutputTracker.java:91)
    at org.richfaces.context.AjaxOutputTracker.getAjaxOutputs(AjaxOutputTracker.java:91).. keep repeating
Jul 15, 2016 4:09:36 PM org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler logException
SEVERE: null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:679)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:643)
    at org.richfaces.context.AjaxOutputTracker.getAjaxOutputs(AjaxOutputTracker.java:86)
    at org.richfaces.context.AjaxOutputTracker.getAjaxOutputs(AjaxOutputTracker.java:91)
    at org.richfaces.context.AjaxOutputTracker.getAjaxOutputs(AjaxOutputTracker.java:91)... keep repeating

Jul 15, 2016 4:09:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/PORTAL].[Faces Servlet] invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/PORTAL] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:679)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:643)
    at org.richfaces.context.AjaxOutputTracker.getAjaxOutputs(AjaxOutputTracker.java:86)
    at org.richfaces.context.AjaxOutputTracker.getAjaxOutputs(AjaxOutputTracker.java:91)
    at org.richfaces.context.AjaxOutputTracker.getAjaxOutputs(AjaxOutputTracker.java:91)..... and so on keep repeating
```

Previously its working in old version.. Any idea on what I am doing wrong? I suspect there is a configuration that I missed that cause this.

Comment: And what is the "old version"? Without PF or with older RF and JSF?

Comment: Without PF and with older RF and JSF.

Comment: And did you solve jQuery versions conflict (because there always is such a conflict)? BTW. This looks kinda suspicious, SOE in findComponent.

Comment: What do you mean suspicious? You mean the problem might be caused by jQuery conflict?

Comment: This means I don't know what it could be and what could cause that. (jQuery could mix `rich:fileUpload` behaviour but it should not cause any server error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing here and there, I actually manage to fix this. The fix is just put limitRender="true" and it fix this problem.

This might be a very simple problem, but I actually don't understand why is this necessary, since I don't put any render in this fileupload. I might miss something in the form. 
Edit: After some check, I find there is ajaxRendered=true in the page, but I don't know why it giving recursive overflow issue, since its not render each other. I might be missing something.